# ASP.NET MVC date in a form submitting to Controller is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im' stucked with a problem concerning a form submitting in a view  to controller.

When I submit the form, I have some variables in a view model and in this form I have a datePicker.
I can see in chrome console event listener breakpoint the right date but when I receive the viewModel in the controller, this value is set to 01/01/0001 (null value interpreted to avoid an error).

Impossible to see my date picked in the form.
What could be wrong ?
How could I troubelshoot that problem ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share your code, at least a minimum working example? Generally, it could be a problem with the format parsing. You could try to set the `DateTime` to `string` in your controller method and set a breakpoint inside. If you get the timestamp as string, it seems related to DateTime parsing.

Comment: Thank you for your welcome Lion.

Little update of my problem :

I have three languages on the web site : french, dutch and english.
It happens when I switch to english language, I have a null value on the controller side.

On the controller side, I'm supposed to receive a date in the viewModel but I receive the date 01/01/0001 00:00:00

Which code could be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Model binding to transfer the data from the form to the model.

There's an [example](http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/globalization-model-binding-datetimes-with-asp-net-mvc) here that might work

Comment: I don't know if it is the trick but sometimes I see the date in the viewModel (looking controller side and sometimes not)

Very disturbing...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the trick but sometimes I see the date in the viewModel (looking controller side and sometimes not)

Very disturbing...